# zip/compression command under Windows environment for COBOL program

Tags: winapi, cobol

I need to issue a zip/compression command from a COBOL program running on Windows platform, is there any built-in Windows specific command line command to zip the list of specified files, I cannot rely on 3rd party zip tools like winzip or 7zip.

I have tried ***compact*** command,  is there any other alternatives to achieve this? please suggest.

Comment: Why do you not want to use 3rd party tools? What problem did COMPACT give you? Did you try COMPRESS? Do you mean built-in to Windows, or built-in to COBOL (you haven't said which compiler you are using)?

Answer (score 0):

Use zip.exe and unzip.exe available from http://www.info-zip.org/. The windows binaries can be downloaded directly from http://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/.